# VIM alignment of taglist window on the right

Tags: vim, taglist

This is my .vimrc:

```
" Key mappings
:map <F12> :WMToggle<cr>

" configuring taglist
    let Tlist_Use_Right_Window = 1
```

these are the plugins I've installed:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john  36129 Nov  8  2010 bufexplorer.vim
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john 147930 Set 21  2007 taglist.vim
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john   2760 Abr  2  2011 vimballPlugin.vim
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john  40661 Jun 30 12:58 winfileexplorer.vim
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john  43224 Jun 30 12:58 winmanager.vim
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john  13418 Jun 30 12:58 wintagexplorer.vim
```

however the taglist window is still being showed on left. What is wrong here?

Comment: You've probably already checked, but if you just do `let Tlist_Use_Right_window` in command mode after entering vim, it does return `#1` right?

Comment: Yeah. The Problem is that winManager creates the tagList window on the left and in someway override the taglist "use_right_window". If I use only taglist it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I solve this:

.vimrc:

```
" winmanager definitions
        ...
    let winManagerWindowLayout = 'FileExplorer|BufExplorer'    " just file and buf exp.

" TagList definitions
        ...
    let Tlist_Use_Right_Window = 1

" mappings
    map <silent> <F12> :TlistToggle<cr> :WMToggle<cr>
```

description: I've extracted TagList from WinManager and defined to open it at the same time WinManager is opened. It's a trick, but works. =D